# Why does $z^{1/n}$ have exactly $n$ distinct values for $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots

In complex analysis, why the set of distinct values of $z^{1/n}$ contains exactly $n$ different values? For example why is $z^{1/3}$ have exactly 3 different roots? I thought that since $$ z^{1/n} = r^{1/n}e^{\frac{i \theta}{n}}$$
implied that there are infinitely many values for different $\theta$.

Comment: For any integer, n, $e^{2\pi i n}= 1$ so two different arguments, $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, such that their difference is a multiple of $2\pi$ have the same exponential: $e^{i\theta_1}= e^{2ni\pi}e^{i\theta_1}= e^{i\theta_1+ 2i\pi n}= e^{i\theta_2}$.

Comment: The complex exponential is not one-to-one

Comment: "there are infinitely many values for different θ" But $\theta$ must be such that $z=re^{i\theta}$. And all these values of $\theta$ yield $n$ distinct values of $e^{i\theta/n}$, hence $n$ distinct values of $re^{i\theta/n}$ if $r\ne0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e^{i\theta/n} = \cos(\theta/n) + i \sin(\theta/n)$$ is a periodic function with period $2\pi n$.

For a particular input value $\theta$, one gets $n$-distinct output values of that function by replacing $\theta$ with $\theta + 2\pi k$ for $k=0,...,n-1$.

Comment: How does that imply that there are n distinct values?

Comment: I added a few words.

Comment: Ok so $e^{i(\theta + 2 \pi k)/n} = \cos((\theta + 2 \pi k)/n) + i \sin((\theta + 2 \pi k)/n) $. Then when the factor $\frac{k}{n}$ "gets" to 1 then the cosine and sine terms return to the beginning of the cycle? However, shouldn't $k$ run up to $n$ and not $n-1$?

Comment: $k$ can run through any set of representatives of addition modulo $n$. So, for example, it can run from $k=1$ to $n$ if you like. I tend to prefer $k=0$ to $n-1$.

Answer (score 2):

For fixed z, it has exactly n values, because $\theta$ only changes modulo $2 \pi$(and then you divide by n so only for n distinct multiples of $2\pi$ will you get values of $\frac{\theta}{n}$ inside $[0,2\pi)$

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by "changes modulo $2\pi$"?

Comment: @daljit97  What I mean is that any two thetas that satisfy the equation differ by a multiple of $2\pi$

Comment: Ok so you are saying $$e^{\frac{i \theta}{n}} = e^{\frac{i (\theta + 2 \pi ik)}{n}}$$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$$?

Comment: Not quite, but close, what I am saying is that for any k, $e^{\frac{i(\theta +2\pi ik)}{n}}$, when raised to the power $n$, are equal and they give exactly n distinct solutions modulo 2$\pi$ for $\theta$

Comment: @daljit97 It's easiest to think about when *z=1*. Plot the roots on the complex plane and they're equally spaced on a unit circle. After $n$ of them you're back where you started and they start repeating.

Answer (score 1):

We may assume without loss of generality that $z=1$, i.e. we are asking for the $n$-th roots of unity. These complex numbers are the roots of the polynomial $X^n-1$. A polynomial of degree $n$ over the complex numbers has exactly $n$ roots. They are different, because the roots of unity form a finite subgroup of $(\Bbb{C},\cdot)$, which has to be cyclic then. So the roots of unity are given by $1,\zeta,\zeta^2,\cdots \zeta^{n-1}$, which are pairwise distinct.